# Oracle Function LAG and order by

Tags: sql, oracle, lag

*Edit Question to reflect true output, see comments.

I have the below data, I need previous program.

TableA

```
StartDate    EndDate     Program     Id 
  1/26/15     2/23/15      Red       1    
  2/24/15     3/31/17      Yellow    1
  5/3/16       6/1/17      Silver    1
  4/1/17       1/31/18     Orange    1
  2/1/18                   Blue      1
```

MyOutput(incorrect)

```
StartDate    EndDate     Program      Prev_program   
  1/26/15     2/23/15      Red                    
  2/24/15     3/31/17      Yellow       Red
  5/3/16       6/1/17      Silver       Yellow
  4/1/17       1/31/18     Orange       Silver
  2/1/18                   Blue         Orange
```

ExpectedOutput:

```
StartDate    EndDate     Program      Prev_program   
  1/26/15     2/23/15      Red                    
  2/24/15     3/31/17      Yellow       Red
  5/3/16       6/1/17      Silver       Red
  4/1/17       1/31/18     Orange       Yellow
  2/1/18                   Blue         Orange
```

I would like to take the previous program when previous program end date is not greater than current startdate.

I used `Lag` which is producing results that I do not want. Lag is not taking into account "program end date is not greater than current startdate."

```
SELECT *
,LAG (PROGRAM, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS PREV_PROGRAM
FROM TABLEA
```

Comment: Why is the program( blue)  and id missing in your  `TableA`?. Was it a mistake or you don't have blue?

Comment: Why does your ExpectedOutput for program Silver (startdate 5/3/16) have a prev_program of "Yellow"? Shouldn't it be Red, since Yellow's end date (3/31/17) is greater than the current startdate (5/3/16)?

Comment: And (Or??) - why do you have a start date of 5/1/18 in the inputs, but 2/1/18 in the outputs?

Comment: @mathguy Question updated.

Comment: @KaushikNayak question updated.

Comment: Shouldn't the value of PREV_PROGRAM for the 4th row be 'Yellow' instead of 'Silver'  since 6/1/2017 > 4/1/2017 ?

Comment: @shrek Yes, sorry about that, question updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this. Not the most elegant or efficient, but it does the job. Two indexes, one on `(id, startdate)` and one on `(id, enddate)` may help with performance (worth testing, anyway). You are missing the `id` column in the output, but I assume it plays a role (and you want the processing to be done separately for each `id`). I wrote the query to work separately for each `id`, even though the test data has only one `id`.

The `with` clause is not part of the query - I included it at the top instead of creating an actual table. You don't need it - start from `SELECT a1.startdate...`

```
with
  table_a ( startdate, enddate, program, id ) as (
    select date '2015-01-26', date '2015-02-23', 'Red'   , 1 from dual union all    
    select date '2015-02-24', date '2017-03-31', 'Yellow', 1 from dual union all
    select date '2016-03-05', date '2017-06-01', 'Silver', 1 from dual union all
    select date '2017-04-01', date '2018-01-31', 'Orange', 1 from dual union all
    select date '2018-02-01', null             , 'Blue'  , 1 from dual
  )
select   a1.startdate, a1.enddate, a1.program, a1.id,
         min(a2.program) keep (dense_rank last order by a2.startdate) as prev_program
from     table_a a1 left outer join table_a a2 
                    on a1.id = a2.id and a1.startdate > a2.enddate
group by a1.startdate, a1.enddate, a1.program, a1.id
;

STARTDATE   ENDDATE     PROGRAM   ID  PREV_PROGRAM
----------  ----------  --------  --  ------------
1/26/2015   2/23/2015   Red        1       
2/24/2015   3/31/2017   Yellow     1  Red   
3/5/2016    6/1/2017    Silver     1  Red   
4/1/2017    1/31/2018   Orange     1  Yellow
2/1/2018                Blue       1  Orange
```